# Google Picker API hide native google drive workspace formats

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

In Google Drive a user can create a new Google Doc/Sheet/Slide/Form etc as a Drive native format. Is there a way to hide these types of files when using the Drive Picker API? I want the user to only see files they have uploaded (or have had shared with them) and not created in Drive.

For example, if I add a view to the picker with ViewId.DOCUMENTS, then everything from Google Doc, txt, and docx show up. Just haven't found away to filter out the Google Doc mime type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `setMimeTypes`? Use it to specify what format do you want to be included.

#### Code:

```
var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
// include only txt and docx files 
view.setMimeTypes("text/plain,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
    .addView(view)
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Drive picker was made for google drive. So it's natural to only have `Views` supporting its native file types.
- What's good is that Google provided us a way of specifying file types not included in their views via `setMimeTypes`
- Currently, I don't find any methods in excluding a certain mime type or view
- Additionally, you can try `setQuery`. I tested this a bit and it seems `view.setQuery("*.docx|*.txt")` will result in all docx and txt files (in my case). You can combine this with or choose it over `setMimeTypes`. Just test it out to see what solution fits you.

#### Reference:

- [Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#view)

Comment: My options here would be to include every extension ever, or to use setQuery to exclude the native google docs (which doesn't exist as far as I know), so I guess I'm not able to do this for now.

Comment: Hi @BrooksLindsey, if we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)